# C Logical Operators Query

Tags: c

In C Logical AND operator if both the operands are non-zero then only condition becomes true.

Then why

```
printf(">>>>>>>>>%d\n", ((4 == 0) && (5 != 6) || (6 != 7)));
```

is printing

```
>>>>>>>>>1
```

Comment: @user4098326 It's not, it's very clear as explained in my answer, I will delete the comment.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [operators' precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

`logical &&` has higher priority than `logical ||`.

Therefore the condition becomes:

```
((4 == 0) && (5 != 6)) || (6 != 7)
```

which is

```
(false && true) || true
```

which is

```
false || true
```

which is

```
true
```

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
printf(">>>>>>>>>%d\n", ((4 == 0) && (5 != 6) || (6 != 7)));
```

`(4 == 0) && (5 != 6)` will evaluate to false, and then you will have

```
printf(">>>>>>>>>%d\n", (0 || (6 != 7)));
```

and since `6 != 7` then it will be

```
printf(">>>>>>>>>%d\n", 1);
```

maybe you wanted to try this

```
printf(">>>>>>>>>%d\n", (4 == 0) && ((5 != 6) || (6 != 7)));
```

read about [operators precedence](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 2):

```
 printf(">>>>>>>>>%d\n", ((4 == 0) && (5 != 6) || (6 != 7)));
```

Operator precedence. `&&` comes before `||`.

6!=7 when I was at school.

Answer (score 1):

It's not doing what you expect because you have both AND (`&&`) and OR (`||`) in the same set of parenthesis.

What you want is:

```
printf(">>>>>>>>>%d\n", ((4 == 0) && ((5 != 6) || (6 != 7))));
```